# How to Populate a ListView From SQL properly?

Tags: android-adapter

i have a problem with ListView(Android).
I get an error trying to run the app on celphone with the code below.
I think its about the ArrayAdapter, due to my websearch, but i cant code the adapter properly.
It says that the last parameter is like and Object[], but, how can make a ArrayList Become an object? Of course, if its the real problem!
Can u guys help me?

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.sql;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Connection con;
    ArrayList<String> resultado = new ArrayList();
    ListView lista;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaView);

        CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();
        checkLogin.execute("");


    }

    public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , resultado.get(0) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultado);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                con = connectionclass();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                } else {
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from geempres where cd_empresa = 1");

                    while(rs.next()) {
                        resultado.add(rs.getString("Nome_completo").trim());
                    }
                    z = resultado.get(0);
                    //con.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }
            return z;
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionclass()
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.0.108:1433/myDB;instanceName=mssqlserver;user=sa;password=123";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        }
        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }


}
```